# Lottie Animation not working with setExitSharedElementCallback android

Tags: java, android, lottie, shared-element-transition

I am working on Android with a Lottie animation. I implemented a shared transition on Lottie from one activity to another activity. But this is not Working. What am I doing wrong in my setExitSharedElementCallback method?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.trans;

import android.app.ActivityOptions;
import android.app.SharedElementCallback;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lottieAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.animation_logo);

        setExitSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
            @Override
            public Parcelable onCaptureSharedElementSnapshot(View sharedElement, Matrix viewToGlobalMatrix, RectF screenBounds) {
                int bitmapWidth = Math.round(screenBounds.width());
                int bitmapHeight = Math.round(screenBounds.height());
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                if (bitmapWidth > 0 && bitmapHeight > 0) {
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.set(viewToGlobalMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate(-screenBounds.left, -screenBounds.top);
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                    canvas.concat(matrix);
                    sharedElement.draw(canvas);
                }
                return bitmap;
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.start_animation).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, lottieAnimationView, "simple_activity_transition");
                startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
            }
        });


    }


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_animation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/animation_logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="click Me" />

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/animation_logo"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:transitionName="simple_activity_transition"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="false"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/dm"
        app:lottie_renderMode="hardware"
        app:lottie_speed="1.2"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activityMain2.java

```
package com.example.trans;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.SharedElementCallback;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView;

import java.util.List;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        setEnterSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
            @Override
            public View onCreateSnapshotView(Context context, Parcelable snapshot) {
                View view = new View(context);
                view.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable((Bitmap) snapshot));
                return view;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSharedElementStart(List<String> sharedElementNames,
                                             List<View> sharedElements,
                                             List<View> sharedElementSnapshots) {
                ImageView sharedElement = findViewById(R.id.animation_logo);
                for (int i = 0; i < sharedElements.size(); i++) {
                    if (sharedElements.get(i) == sharedElement) {
                        View snapshot = sharedElementSnapshots.get(i);
                        Drawable snapshotDrawable = snapshot.getBackground();
                        sharedElement.setBackground(snapshotDrawable);
                        sharedElement.setImageAlpha(0);
                        forceSharedElementLayout();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            private void forceSharedElementLayout() {
                ImageView sharedElement = findViewById(R.id.animation_logo);
                int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(sharedElement.getWidth(),
                        View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(sharedElement.getHeight(),
                        View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                int left = sharedElement.getLeft();
                int top = sharedElement.getTop();
                int right = sharedElement.getRight();
                int bottom = sharedElement.getBottom();
                sharedElement.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
                sharedElement.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSharedElementEnd(List<String> sharedElementNames,
                                           List<View> sharedElements,
                                           List<View> sharedElementSnapshots) {
                ImageView sharedElement =  findViewById(R.id.animation_logo);
                sharedElement.setBackground(null);
                sharedElement.setImageAlpha(255);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/animation_logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:transitionName="simple_activity_transition"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="false"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/dm"
        app:lottie_renderMode="hardware"
        app:lottie_speed="1.2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Styles

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/explode</item>
    </style>
```